# Drawing Time Sequence for different stations

Tags: javascript, python, graphics

I have a simulator which simulates the the behavior of 802.11n network. The simulator generates XML file which contains information about the back-off procedure happening in each station in the simulation campaign like:

1. When a station was granted an access to the medium.
2. How much time the station was backed off.
3. How much time the station is occupying a channel to send a packet.

So my question, is there any existing library in Python or Java that might help to draw these sequences, something like the attached image [image].

Comment: http://www.umlgraph.org/

Answer (score 0):

[graphviz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz) is probably a good fit.

Here is a [Tutorial](http://matthiaseisen.com/articles/graphviz/)